# Use case: To construct a message that disppears after sometime in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, amazon-sqs

I have scenario where i want to send message to a alert service that would process the message and would send it to hipchat.

But I want the message to be active only for a minute. If hipchat is down (hypothetical) then the message should not be sent to hipchat.

I am using kafka so one of the service sends the message to kafka then the message is consumed by alert service(it polls the service) which processes the message (kafka consumer) while processing it checks that the time now and the time of the message is not greater than one minute. If not, it sends the message to hipchat aynchronously.

Enhancement:

1. I want a way to construct a self destruction message so that i automatically disappears after one minute. Is there a way to do it with kafka ? OR is there a better alternate than kafka (flink/sqs). If yes, how?

Comment: *checks that the time now and the time of the message is not greater than one minute* - What is the issue with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Kafka topic configurations `retention.ms` and `delete.retention.ms` as described in the [Topic Level Configs](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#topicconfigs).

The `retention.ms` should be set to 1 minute (60000 ms) and the `delete.retention.ms` should be set to 0 in your case. That way, the messages will stay in the Kafka Topic for one minute before they get deleted. However, that also means that you might loose messages if your consumer takes more then one minute to consume all messages (especially when reading a topic from beginning).

Details on those configurations are:

> **delete.retention.ms**: The amount of time to retain delete tombstone markers for log compacted topics. This setting also gives a bound on the time in which a consumer must complete a read if they begin from offset 0 to ensure that they get a valid snapshot of the final stage (otherwise delete tombstones may be collected before they complete their scan).

> **retention.ms**: This configuration controls the maximum time we will retain a log before we will discard old log segments to free up space if we are using the "delete" retention policy. This represents an SLA on how soon consumers must read their data. If set to -1, no time limit is applied.

Comment: @eatpaybong did this answer your question?